# Batch file to find number of folders under particular folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder named Test under C:\Users\Desktop\Test
I want to find count of all sub folders under folders named Zone inside Test. 
For example if we have folders like:

```
Test->Zone->Folder1 / Folder2
Test->Testing->Zone->Folder3 / Folder5
```

So in above scenario we will have count as 4.

I tried this script but is not working right?

```
@echo off
pushd C:\Users\Desktop\Test
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0

for /d %%d in ('DIR /a:d /b Zone*') do (
    set /a count+=1
    @echo !count!. %%d 
)
pause
```

Comment: You can't combine a `for /d` loop with a `dir` command. This does only work with a `for /f` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
pushd "C:\Users\Desktop\Test"
set /a count=0
for /d /r %%i in (zone\*.*) do set /a count+=1
popd
echo %count% folder(s^)
endlocal
```